# My query has a NOT IN, and suddenly stopped showing results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that runs every day, and suddenly it stopped outputting results. It doesn't output an error, just no results.

Note that this query includes a `NOT IN` operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem of `NOT IN` behavior, check out the MySQL version of it:

- [MySQL "Not IN" query suddenly stopped returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006945/mysql-not-in-query-suddenly-stopped-returning-results)

With BigQuery:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) x
), data2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2]) x
)

SELECT * FROM data
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT * FROM data2)

3
```

But then if you have a null in data2:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) x
), data2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2,null]) x
)

SELECT * FROM data
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT * FROM data2)

# no results
```

Instead you could do a `LEFT JOIN`, or a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2,3]) x
), data2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2]) x
)

SELECT * FROM data a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM data2 b WHERE a.x=b.x)

3
```